# How to Get Row Count Depending on Column Values using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am querying a mysql table and want results group by date, and one column name is type. There are two value for the type `call` and `email`. I want to find count for `call` and `email` for each day.

- Find the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c08e65/6) here

I am trying with this query. Which only gets me total counts:

```
SELECT Date(date) date,
COUNT(type) total,
COUNT(type='email') emails,
COUNT(type='call') calls

from leads 
where user_id = 1 
GROUP BY Date(date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM()` instead. The `type='email'` in the function returns either 0 (false) or 1 (true).

```
SELECT Date(date) date,
COUNT(type) total,
SUM(type='email') emails,
SUM(type='call') calls
from leads 
where user_id = 1 
GROUP BY Date(date)
```